# Gradle run copy task to add js files in build/classes after IDE(intellj) compile/make project

Tags: java, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

Hi all and thanks for taking time to help in advance. This is the first question I'm posting so please do let me know if this can be improved.
I'm a newbie to gradle and this is my first project.
I have **gradle.build** included at the bottom which downloads tar from nexus repo and then i have tasks to untar and copy the files to `$buildDir/classes/main/static/sisplayer`. Then i have a `war.dependsOn copyPlayer` to have the files ready to be added to it. The problem is that i can get to files to be included in the war to work on server and have `bootRun{}.dependsOn copyPlayer` to have the files before running the app by `gradle bootRun`
but i dont get the files when i run the app on intellij using the main class. I assume i need to hook up the task to be executed before project is compiled so i tried

```
compileJava.dependsOn copyPlayer
```

but that is giving out error. I've also tried to to use hooks like

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    preBuild.dependsOn copyPlayer
}
```

as suggested in [here](http://blogs.candoerz.com/question/186664/run-task-before-compilation-using-android-gradle-plugin.aspx) but that's also comes out with an error. can someone please help. Ive tried to look up but couldnt find a solution.

Also are there other thing in the config that I can improve as this is my first gradle project.
The whole config is as under.

```
 buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath 'org.springframework:springloaded:1.2.6.RELEASE'
    }
}


plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.2.1"
    id "net.saliman.cobertura" version "2.3.2"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
def playerVersion= "0.4.0-36"
idea {
    module {
        inheritOutputDirs = false
        outputDir = file("$buildDir/classes/main/")
    }

}

war {

    baseName = 'streaming_demo'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    from("$buildDir/classes/main/static/jsplayer"){
        into("WEB-INF/classes/static/jsplayer")
    }

}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://example.com:6590/nexus/content/repositories/frontend-artifacts"
    }

    maven {
        url "example.com:6590/nexus/content/groups/public/"
    }
    maven {
        url "http://example.com:6590/nexus/content/repositories/releases/"
    }
    maven {
        url "http://example.com:6590/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/" 
    }
    maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    }

    mavenCentral()
    }

    configurations {
        jsPlayer
        providedRuntime
    }
    dependencies {
    //  compile group: 'javax.el', name: 'javax.el-api', version: '2.2.4'
        sisPlayer "com.example:jsplayer:$playerVersion@tar.gz"
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
            exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
        }
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services')
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
        compile("org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4")
        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.24'
        compile 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc41:4.1'

        runtime('com.h2database:h2')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

    //  dependencies for using Spock
    compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.1"
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4"

    testRuntime "cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1"          // allows mocking of 

    classes (in addition to interfaces)
        testRuntime "org.objenesis:objenesis:2.1"
        // allows mocking of classes without default constructor (together with CGLIB)
    }
    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = '3.1'
    }
    task extractPlayer(type: Copy){
        from tarTree(configurations.jsPlayer.singleFile)
        into "$buildDir/testplayerDownload/"

    }
    task copyPlayer(type: Copy) {
        dependsOn extractPlayer
        from "$buildDir/testplayerDownload/dist"
        into "$buildDir/classes/main/static/jsplayer"
        doLast {
            delete("$buildDir/testplayerDownload/")
        }
    }

    build{}.doLast{
        tasks.extractPlayer.execute()
        tasks.copyPlayer.execute()
    }

    war.dependsOn copyPlayer

    bootRun {}.dependsOn copyPlayer

    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        preBuild.dependsOn copyPlayer
    }
     cobertura {
        coverageFormats = ['xml']
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting with `compileJava.dependsOn copyPlayer` ?

Comment: @Opal i was getting compile.java method not found on gradle build earlier but now after trying again it runs without errors but i'm still not getting the files in the jsplayer dir when i run on intellij.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of googling i was able to get help from one of the dev from Gradle dev team and found its out of Gradle's scope/responsibility to execute a task before intelliJ compiles the code. This is because intelliJ uses its own compiler and not the Gradle's Build/Compile task. An easy way to have intelliJ run a task before compilation is by right clicking on the task you want to run before compilation from Gradle View in intelliJ and select  `Run Before Build`